# Proving an Inequality in Fourier Transformation

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, fourier-analysis, induction

Let $f: [0,2\pi]\to \mathbb C$ be an continuously differentiable function with $f^{(j)}(0)=f^{(j)}(2\pi)$ for $j=0,...,m-2$ and let the fourier transformation $\hat f(k)= \int^{2\pi}_{0}f(x)e^{ikx}\,dx$, $(k\in \mathbb R)$

Show that a $C>0$ exists such that $\forall k \in \mathbb N$  such that

$$|\hat f(k)|\leq \frac{C}{|k|^{m}}$$

Normally, I would attempt to explain my thought process but given that we have just started with fourier transformations I really am in the dark. My only suggestion would be to prove via induction?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By definition we have $$\widehat{f}(k)= \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} kx} \mathrm{d} x.$$
Now apply integration by parts. What is the antiderivate of $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} kx}$?

**Added Solution**: As in the comment indicated, we can apply $(m-1)$-times partial integration to obtain
$$\widehat{f}(k) = \big( - \frac{1}{\mathrm{i} k} \big)^{m-1} \int_0^{2\pi} f^{m-1}(x) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x k} \, \mathrm{d} x.$$
Note that this formula may fail to be true for the next step, because $f^{(m-1)}(0) \neq f^{(m-1)}(2\pi)$, i.e. the boundary values may not vanish. However, what happens if we again integrate by parts?

Comment: $\frac{1}{ik}e^{ikx}$

Comment: Yes! So using partial integration, using $f(0) = f(2\pi)$, we find Yes! So using partial integration in combination with $f(0) = f(2\pi)$ (and $\exp(2 \pi \mathrm{i}  n) =1$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$) we find $\widehat{f}(k) = \frac{f(2\pi)-f(0)}{\mathrm{i}k}  - \frac{1}{\mathrm{i} k} \int_0^{2\pi} f'(x) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} kx } \mathrm{d} x =- \frac{1}{\mathrm{i} k} \int_0^{2\pi} f'(x) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} kx } \mathrm{d} x$. How we could continue?

Comment: Another partial integration?

Comment: Yes! I have added this step to my answer and an another hint.

Comment: Ok, I end up with $\hat f(k)=(-\frac{1}{ik})^{(m-1)})(\frac{f^{(m-1)}(2\pi)-f^{(m-1)}(0)}{ik}-\int f^{m}(x)e^{ixk}dx$ how can i say it is bounded though

Comment: There is a typing error: We have $\widehat{f}(k) = (\frac{1}{\mathrm{i}k})^m \big( f^{(m-1)}(2\pi) - f^{(m-1)}(0) - \int_0^{2\pi} f^{(m)}(x) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} x k} \mathrm{d} x \big)$. The terms in the second bracket can be bounded as follows: $f^{(m-1)}(2\pi) - f^{(m-1)}(0)$ is just a constant. And $\big| \int_0^{2\pi} f^{(m)}(x) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} x k} \mathrm{d} x \big| \leq 2\pi \max_{x \in [0,2\pi]} |f^{(m)}(x)|$ is also a finite constant. (Of course, the $C>0$ depends on the function $f$.)